# using python tkinter to automatically populate a field based on the selection of another Combobox with data taken from excel table

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I have an excel sheet with a table, which has 3 rows. I have written a python code to get the values of the first combobox from the first column of the excel table, and saving it to a new excel. I want to fill 2 more columns in the new excel based on the selected data from the combobox, and also display it on the app window.

Please let me know how I can do this.

This is my code for what I achieved so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Entry, ttk
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Load the xlsx file, then store the value of each column in the "elements" list
wb = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\Chinnu\Downloads\exampleapp\testdata.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
wBook = load_workbook('storingfile.xlsx')
sheet = wBook.active

m_row = ws.max_row
m_col=  ws.max_column
print("total rows of the excel: ",m_row)
MaterialDescription = ws['A2':'A10']
elements = []       

#to get the list of column values
for cell in MaterialDescription:
    for x in cell:
        y = x.value
        elements.append(y)
        print(y)
data1 = [combodata.get()]
        sheet.append(data1)
        wBook.save('storingfile.xlsx')

# Tkinter stuff
win = Tk()
clicked = StringVar()

#label and combobox, binding
ttk.Label(text="Material Description:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
combodata = ttk.Combobox(win, values=elements)
combodata.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
combodata['values'] = elements
combodata.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_input)
wBook.save('storingfile.xlsx')


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring `data1` at that point in your code?

Comment: data1 is just a variable to save the selected value from the combobox to the new excel file.

Comment: combodata is referenced before it's declaration.